# Instantiating a TreeMap using a Comparator which should be able to access the said TreeMap

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator, treemap

I'm trying to instantiate a `TreeMap` using a `Comparator` which should be able to access the said `TreeMap`, i.e. the one it *will* be used for (I guess that "*will*" must precisly be the problem...):

```java
final Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer i = map.get(o1);
        // Error: "the local variable map may not have been initialized"
        return ...;
    }

});
```

I can get why this error occurs, since when instantiating the `Comparator<String>`, the `map` variable isn't initialized yet, but is there any workaround solution?

A solution would have been a `setComparator` method in [the `TreeMap` implementation](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/TreeMap.java.html), but its `comparator` field has been declared as final:

```java
final Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer i = map.get(o1);
        return ...;
    }

};
// map.setComparator(comparator);
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort on the values?

Comment: As per my understanding a comparator should only use the values that are supplied as parameters in compare method. If you use other values you would end up tying it to the state of outside values and then the comparator would not be consistent. This also explains why the comparator is final. If you want 2 different comparators you are better off creating 2 tree map instances.

Comment: Would `Map<Integer, String>` be out of the question?

Comment: Well, if you can't assign the `Comparator` to the `TreeMap`, why not do it the other way around? You couldn't go with an anonymous class any longer, but what's the catch?

Comment: This still won't possibly work.  A `TreeMap` will just blow up and become completely unusable if you try to compare keys with the value in the map itself.  You _can't do this_.

Comment: After you created TreeMap you can't change comparing method used by it. TreeMap only uses compare method of Comparator. Not, you can't do what you want because your Comparator is not inner class of TreeMap and your Comparator should be created before TreeMap is created !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two months later, after having relooked into [the answer @hd1 gave me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807812/1225328) (which doesn't work *as is* actually), here is  a possible solution:

```java
public class SortedByValueMap<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<K> {

    private final Map<K, V> map = new TreeMap<K, V>();

    private class CustomTreeMap<KK extends K, VV extends V> extends TreeMap<KK, VV> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9196929305071517886L;

        private CustomTreeMap(Comparator<KK> c) {
            super(c);
        }

        @Override
        public VV put(KK key, VV value) {
            map.put(key, value);
            return super.put(key, value);
        };

        @Override
        public VV remove(Object key) {
            map.remove(key);
            return super.remove(key);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
        return map.get(o1).compareTo(map.get(o2));
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return new CustomTreeMap<K, V>(this);
    }

}
```

Then:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new SortedByValueMap<String, Integer>().getMap();
map.put("r", 2);
map.put("b", 0);
map.put("a", 1);
System.out.println(map); // prints {b=0, a=1, r=2}
```

But anyway, it has to be considered as a technical challenge solution rather than a real efficient tool though (since two identical parallel maps are created), so use it sparingly... `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you implement Comparator on your class and pass `this` to the TreeMap constructor, example:

```
class MyClass implements Comparator<MyClass> {
private String property;
@Override // java.util.Comparator.compare
public int compare(MyClass o1,
            MyClass o2) {
return o1.getProperty().compare(o2.getProperty());
}
@Override // java.util.Comparator.equals
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this.getProperty().equals(o.getProperty());
}

public String getProperty() {
    return this.property;
}

public void setProperty(String myPropertyValue) {
    property = myPropertyValue;
}

TreeMap <String, MyClass> myMap = null;

public MyClass() {
  myMap = new TreeMap<String, MyClass>(this);
}
```

If you need further assistance, do leave a comment with more information as to your specific case.