# Trying to simplify the creation of a sorted-by-value map throws a StackOverflowException

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to answer [my own old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807453/1225328) based on the sole (non working) answer I had.

The idea was to simplify the creation of a sorted-by-value map:

```java
public class SortedByValueMap<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<K> {

    private final Map<K, V> map = new TreeMap<K, V>(this);

    @Override
    public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
        return map.get(o1).compareTo(map.get(o2)); // <-- line #19
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

}
```

Then, when instantiating it:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new SortedByValueMap<String, Integer>().getMap();
map.put("a", 9); // works great
map.put("z", 0); // throws a StackOverflowException
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:255)
    at main.Main$SortedByValueMap.compare(Main.java:19)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:351)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:322)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:255)
```

Any idea why it is looping and how to solve it?

Comment: Does it throw a `StackOverflow` error when you're trying to put only one key/value pair ?

Comment: @ZouZou No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `get()` method calls the `compare()` method of the provided comparator - your class - and your `compare()` method calls `get()` so we end up running in circles

```
at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:255) <--
at main.Main$SortedByValueMap.compare(Main.java:19)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:351)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:322)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:255) <--
```

This loop is entered because `TreeMap` uses the provided `Comparator` when you `put` an element into a non empty map

Comment: Right, thanks, it helped me to [answer my old question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17218536/1225328) `;)`